# Is there a way to disable autouninstaller from uninstaller file?

Tags: chocolatey

I have a jar file I unzip to a directory for install and remove contents from directory during uninstall, but autouninstaller is throwing "Cannot uninstall a non-existent package."
Is there a way to disable autouninstaller from uninstaller file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer from [Gary Ewan Park @gep13](https://gitter.im/chocolatey/chocolatey.org?at=599f0a7d76a757f808dc56e9) in Chocolatey Gitter Channel.

> This is possible as of 0.10.8 of chocolatey https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/1257

---

Basically adding a .skipAutoUninstall under tools dir will disable autouninstall feature in 0.10.8 version of chocolatey (which is not released at the time of this writing).

Comment: You can add the file now and it will take effect when the new version is released.